# AttributeError at /add/...Getting 'str' object has no attribute 'get' in Django.Atrri

Tags: python, django

**models.py**
I write this code for creating a form which has two fileds named Title and Desc
from django.db import models.Here is models.py code.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    desc = models.TextField()
```

And Here is forms.py Code
**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm,AuthenticationForm,UsernameField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','desc']
        # label = {'title':'Title','desc':'Description'}
        widgets={'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'desc':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'})}
```

Here is the views.py code
**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import SignUpForm,LoginForm,PostForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from .models import Post

def add_post(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PostForm(request.method)
            if form.is_valid():
                title1 = form.cleaned_data['title']
                description = form.cleaned_data['desc']
                pst = Post(title=title1,desc=description)
                pst.save()
                form = PostForm()
        else:
            form = PostForm()
        return render(request,'blog_app/addpost.html',{'form':form})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

Here is the addpost.html
**addpost.html**

```
{% extends 'blog_app/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <h3 class="text-black my-5 alert alert-success">Add Post</h3>
        <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary">
        <a href='{% url "dashboard"%}' class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
    </form> 
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

But When I click on Add Button I got this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmR7j.png)

What is the solution of it
Here is Url.py code
**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from blog_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home),
    path('about/', views.about,name='about'),
    path('contact/', views.contact,name='contact'),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard,name='dashboard'),
    path('signup/', views.signup,name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.user_login,name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout,name='logout'),
    path('add/', views.add_post,name='addpost'),
    path('update/<int:id>/', views.update_post,name='updatepost'),
    path('delete/<int:id>/', views.delete_post,name='deletepost'),
]
```

And This is the error Shows in my terminal
[terminal img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB5OE.png)

Comment: include the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

This line in your view

```py
form = PostForm(request.method)
```

should be

```py
form = PostForm(request.POST)
```